# Caracter vazio saindo no Html

Tags: php

A página é:

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/_required/email2.php

O código é:

```
<?php
    require_once "../_controlls/_conexao/Conexao.php";
    require_once "../_controlls/_util/PhpUtil.php";     
    require_once "../_controlls/_models/Emails.php";
    require_once "../_controlls/_daos/EmailsDao.php";
    require_once "../_controlls/_util/Constantes.php";

    $connection = new Conexao(); 
    $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
    $constantes = new Constantes();  
    $phpUtil = new PhpUtil();

    $_POST["assunto"] = 1;
    $_POST["nome"] = "Caca";
    $_POST["email"] = "aa@bb.com";
    $_POST["telefone"] = 3333333333;
    $_POST["descricao"] = "Teste";
    $_POST["qual"] = "";

    $assunto = $phpUtil->contatoTipos($_POST["assunto"]);   
    $emailsDao = new EmailsDao($conexao);

    $email = new Emails(
                     date("Y-m-d"), 
                     "n", 
                     $_POST["nome"], 
                     $_POST["email"], 
                     preg_replace( '#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST["telefone"] ),
                     $_POST["assunto"], 
                     $_POST["descricao"]);

    $emailsDao->cadastrar($email);

    $outro = $_POST["assunto"] == 6 ? "<b>Qual:</b> ".$_POST["qual"]."<br /><br />" : "";   

    $texto  = "<h2>".$constantes->getTituloSite()."</h2><br />";
    $texto .= "<img style='display:block; margin:0 auto;' src='".$constantes->getHttpSite()."/_img/logo.png' />";
    $texto .= "<b>Olá, você nos enviou um e-mail com a seguinte mensagem:</b><br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Nome:</b> ".$_POST["nome"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Telefone:</b> ".$_POST["telefone"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST["email"]."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= "<b>Interesse:</b> ".$assunto."<br /><br />";
    $texto .= $outro;
    $texto .= "<b>Descrição:</b><br />".nl2br($_POST["descricao"])."<br /><br /><br />";
    $texto .= "Estaremos respondendo o mais rápido possível<br /><br />";

    require_once "../_controlls/_models/EmailEnviar.php";
    require_once "../_controlls/_daos/EmailEnviarDao.php";

    $html = "<!doctype html>
             <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <title>".$constantes->getTituloSite()."/title>
              </head>           
              <body>".$texto."</body>
             </html>";

    $assuntoCodificado = sprintf('=?%s?%s?%s?=', 'UTF-8', 'Q', quoted_printable_encode("Re: ".$assunto));


    $emailEnviar = new EmailEnviar( 
          $_POST["nome"], 
          $_POST["email"],
          $constantes->getTituloSite(), 
          "bb@aa.com",
          $assuntoCodificado,
          $texto
    );

    $emailEnviarDao = new EmailEnviarDao();

    $enviarEmail = $emailEnviarDao->enviaEmail($emailEnviar);   

    if ($enviarEmail["success"] == 1) {

        var_dump ("OK");

    } else {

        var_dump ("ERRO");

    }

?>
```

Quando da certo, o `html` deveria `retornar`

"OK"

Quando da errado, o `html` deveria `retornar`

"ERRO"

De fato isto esta acontecendo. Porem, com espaços no inicio.

" OK"  e " ERRO"

Isso está me trazendo problemas na hora pegar esse resultado com `JQuery AJax`

Isso poderia ser resolvido dando um `trim` no `ajax` mas gostaria de entender de onde está vindo este espaço em branco uma vez que nenhum dos arquivos envolvidos tem assinatura BOM.

Saída `html` no `Ctrl+U`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique se há um echo em algum arquivo importado, não parece vir desse arquivo

Comment: procurei em todos. Nenhum tem echo. Como são classes ou arquivos de funções só tem returns

Comment: Vá pondo echo '1'; echo '2'; echo '3'; e sucessivamente pelo código que você vai ver em qual trecho o espaço é inserido. Muito mais rápido que ficar quebrando a cabeça. Ponha o primeiro logo depois do <?php , depois dos require/includes etc. Onde o espaço aparecer, vc vai cercando.

Answer (score 1):

Esse espaço extra só pode estar a vir de um dos `require_once`.

Verifica todos esses ficheiros, e garante que não tens nenhum espaço antes do `<?php` e se a terminação `?>` existe nesses ficheiros.

Comment: Entendi o problema. O detalhe não era o ?> mas sim o que tem após ele.
Não deve ter nada. Mas mesmo assim, aparece um espaço após o html

Comment: @CarlosRocha, se essa resposta te ajudou você pode marca-la como aceita

Answer (score 0):

Têm certeza de que isso de fato está acontecendo?

Tente utilizar o `var_dump` para mostrar **"OK"** e **"ERRO"**, esta função retorna além da string o total de caracteres que ela possui. Você pode estar se confundindo devido ao fato de que alguns navegadores definem um `margin` padrão para a `tag` `body`

Comment: De fato, o retorno de var_dump dá apenas 4 caracters. Mas na página, como voce mesmo pode conferir pelo link que deixei na pergunta, tem um caracter vazio antes da impressão da var_dump

Comment: Acessei o link, e é exatamente o que eu falei, não existe esse carácter vazio, você pode estar se confundindo com o margin como eu citei na resposta

Comment: Não estou confundindo não. Quando pergunto ao JQuery, ele informa ter mais que 4 caracters

Comment: viu o Ctrl+U? Viu que antes da saída do html tem um espaço em branco?

Comment: Experimente remove a tag de fechamento do php: ?> já que no seu código não têm html a tag de fechamento não é necessária

Comment: eu editei a pergunta e adicionei uma imagem mostrando o que estou dizendo no final da pergunta. Note o espaço antes de String e ainda tem uma quebra de linha depois

Comment: retirei o ?> e continuou o problema

Answer (score 0):

Na saída tem isso

```
[carriage return][space][space]string(2) "OK"[space]
```

Os códigos ASCII

```
[carriage return] 13
[space] 32
```

Pelo view-source do Google Chrome o carriage return não quebra a linha, dando impressão de ser um caracter de espaço. Mas se você copiar e colar num editor de textos poderá enxergar.

Provavelmente alguns desses arquivos inclusos estão soltando esses caracteres.

Revise os códigos dos seguintes arquivos:

```
../_controlls/_conexao/Conexao.php
../_controlls/_util/PhpUtil.php     
../_controlls/_models/Emails.php
../_controlls/_daos/EmailsDao.php
../_controlls/_util/Constantes.php
../_controlls/_models/EmailEnviar.php
../_controlls/_daos/EmailEnviarDao.php
```

Note que ainda há um espaço a mais após o `var_dump()`, mas não é possível determinar pelo código que postou.

Provavelmente é a mesma situação, algum outro arquivo incluso soltando caracteres sem controle adequado, em algum local após o `var_dump()`.

Esteja ciente também que `var_dump()` insere uma quebra de linha no começo e no final. Experimente aplicar somente um `echo 'OK'`, pois `var_dump()` é usado normalmente para depuração.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui com a ajuda de todos!

Seguinte: Quando você tem um `JQuery .load` ou um `Ajax .load`, essas funções desejam receber apenas o `result` desejado.

Quando fazemos, por exemplo, `?>` e logo após temos espaços, quebras de linha e outras coisas, então esses detalhes também vão para o `result` junto com as variáveis.

Caso não precise validar nada, então não terá problemas com o retorno. 
Mas, se precisar fazer qualquer comparação, será necessário antes fazer um trim() para retirar os caracteres indesejados caso existam.